# How can an uncountable noun be associated with plural nouns?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

> I collected data on income in some countries and found that (all) the
>   income data **is close to each other**.

I am not sure that the expression "**is** close to **each other**" in the sentence above I created is correct.  I use data as a singular mass noun.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are using data as a singular mass noun, *each other* can only be used when there is a plurality of subjects.

Therefore, only the following versions can be correct:

> 1. The income data **is** close to **itself**.
>    The income datum **is** close to **itself**.

These are grammatical, even if something being "close to itself" is strange. It would likely be rephrased, but the sentence is syntactically sound.

> 2. The income data **are** close to **each other**.
>    The points of the income data **are** close to **each other**.
>    The income data values **are** close to **each other**.
>    The income datums **are** closed to **each other**.

Those are four variations of the plural use. I provided the extra examples as alternatives to using just *data*.

Note that [*datums*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/datum), while obscure, is still a valid plural form of the singular *datum*. However, since it is obscure, you might want to avoid it.

---

Now, consider the following:

> My body is long. [singular body]

*but*

> The arms of my body are long. [plural arms]

Finally, look again at the second version of the sentence I used in the plural case:

> The **points** *of the income data* **are** close to **each other**.

It's deliberately vague. You could interpret *the income data* as either singular or plural—and it wouldn't make any difference to the rest of the sentence, because the plural *are* goes with the plural *points*.

This particular construction may best match your need for a singular mass noun interpretation of *data* while still preserving the idea of it containing, or being spread across, several points.

Comment: You said "It's deliberately vague".  I would like to remove the vagueness.  I think this sentence may be interpreted that the points of the income data regarding one country are close to each other to form a straight line graph like y = a constant value.  How about "the income data is similar among all the countries" ?

Comment: @rama9 I was speaking of the syntax. There is no way of knowing if *the income data* is singular or plural; but, it doesn't matter. Regardless of interpretation, because it's preceded by a plural noun, the version of the sentence remains grammatical.